# Find matching column interval in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with multiple columns were their values increase from some value between 0 and 1 for column `A` up to column `E` which is always 1 (representing cumulative probabilities).

```
ID          A    B    C    D    E     SIM
1:          0.49 0.64 0.86 0.97 1.00  0.98
2:          0.76 0.84 0.98 0.99 1.00  0.87
3:          0.32 0.56 0.72 0.92 1.00  0.12
```

The column `SIM` represents a column with random uniform numbers.

I wish to add a new column `SIM_CAT` with values equal to the column-name which value is the right boundary of the interval in which the value in column `SIM` falls:

```
ID          A    B    C    D    E     SIM  SIM_CAT
1:          0.49 0.64 0.86 0.97 1.00  0.98 E
2:          0.76 0.84 0.98 0.99 1.00  0.87 C
3:          0.32 0.56 0.72 0.92 1.00  0.12 A
```

I there a concise way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare columns with `SIM` and use [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) to find the 1st greater value:

```
cols = list('ABCDE')
df['SIM_CAT'] = df[cols].ge(df.SIM, axis=0).idxmax(axis=1)
df
   ID     A     B     C     D    E   SIM SIM_CAT
0  1:  0.49  0.64  0.86  0.97  1.0  0.98       E
1  2:  0.76  0.84  0.98  0.99  1.0  0.87       C
2  3:  0.32  0.56  0.72  0.92  1.0  0.12       A
```

If `SIM` can contain values greater than 1:

```
cols = list('ABCDE')
df['SIM_CAT'] = None
df.loc[df.SIM <= 1, 'SIM_CAT'] = df[cols].ge(df.SIM, axis=0).idxmax(axis=1)

df
   ID     A     B     C     D    E   SIM SIM_CAT
0  1:  0.49  0.64  0.86  0.97  1.0  0.98       E
1  2:  0.76  0.84  0.98  0.99  1.0  0.87       C
2  3:  0.32  0.56  0.72  0.92  1.0  0.12       A
```

Comment: If your replace the the first SIM (0.98) by 1.98, `idxmax` returns `A` instead of `NaN`

Comment: @Corralien Yeah, I'm assuming `SIM` is between 0 and 1 since it's a probability. But it's probably better to explicitly mark that out.